# Selecting row from a group on highest score based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

**Data**

```
     Sentence  Score_Unigram  Score_Bigram  versionId
0    As of   Dat              5             1  269004158
1     Date Docum              4             3  269004158
2    As of   Dat              4             1  269004158
3     Date Docum              5             3  345973060
4    x Indicate               4             1  372529352
5     Date Docum              5             3  372529352
6   1 Financial               9             1  372529352
7   020 per shar              2             0  372529352
8     Date $ in               8             1  372529352
9     Date $ in               9             4  372529352
10   4 ---------              4             1  372529352
11    Date Begin              1             0  372529352
```

**Required Output**

```
       Sentence  Score_Unigram  Score_Bigram  versionId
0   As of   Dat              5             1  269004158
3    Date Docum              5             3  345973060
9    Date $ in               9             4  372529352
```

> Objective

Group by version id, get the row with max Score_unigram, if results are more than one, then check the Score_Bigram column and get the row with the highest value (If there are more than one such rows return all)

> What have I tried

```
maximum = 0
index_to_pick = []

for index,row_data in a.iterrows():
    if row_data['Score_Unigram'] > maximum:
        maximum = row_data['Score_Unigram']
        score_bigram = row_data['Score_Bigram']
        index_to_pick.append(index)

    elif row_data['Score_Unigram'] == maximum:
        if row_data['Score_Bigram'] > score_bigram:

            maximum = row_data['Score_Unigram']
            score_bigram = row_data['Score_Bigram']
            index_to_pick = []
            index_to_pick.append(index)

        elif row_data['Score_Bigram'] == score_bigram:
            index_to_pick.append(index)

   a.loc[[index_to_pick[0]]]
```

**Output**

```
       Sentence  Score_Unigram  Score_Bigram  versionId
5    Date $ in               9             4  372529352
```

Okay the approach is not pretty i guess (since data is large), looking for a efficient one.
I tried `idxmax` but that returns the only the top one. Might be a duplicate but wasn't able to find one. Thanks for the help!!.

Comment: `df.sort_values(['Score_Unigram','Score_Bigram'],ascending=False).head(1)` ?

Comment: @anky_91 would love to but not on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - first by `max` of first column `Score_Unigram` and then by `Score_Bigram`:

```
df = df[ df['Sentence'].duplicated(keep=False)]
df = df[df.groupby('Sentence')['Score_Unigram'].transform('max') == df['Score_Unigram']]
df = df[df.groupby(['Sentence', 'Score_Unigram'])['Score_Bigram'].transform('max') == df['Score_Bigram']]
print (df)
     Sentence  Score_Unigram  Score_Bigram  versionId
0   As of Dat              5             1  269004158
3  Date Docum              5             3  345973060
5  Date Docum              5             3  372529352
9   Date $ in              9             4  372529352
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reponse, but this might not work  ( correct me if i am wrong) for groups right, if there are multiple version ids.. (sorry updated the ques now)

Comment: thanks works smoothly (small thing groupby had to be done on versionId but anyways works fine, i made the changes for myself)

Answer (score 1):

try this on your `df`   :

`df.sort_values(['Score_Unigram','Score_Bigram'],ascending=False).head(1)`

Output:

```
    Sentence     Score_Unigram  Score_Bigram  versionId
5   Date $ in               9             4  372529352
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need to sort data, just compare to the `max` value of those 2 columns

```
df[ (df['Score_Unigram'] == df['Score_Unigram'].max()) & 
    (df['Score_Bigram'] == df['Score_Bigram'].max()) ]
```